# SSI menu links need color change: CSS or HTML?

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, colors, ssi

Have a menu as an SSI.  I wish to change color of displayed SSI links on page.  My reading shows I can use CSS to change displayed link color, so created div around the menu and unique div id as well as CSS for the div.  The div ID is “menu”.

CSS

```
#menu {
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
    margin-left: 25px;

    a { color: #FFFF00; }
}
```

Only the unvisited links need to change, hence the single line.  This code makes no changes to my links:  they show  default #0000EE. This code does provide the needed margin, so the server is reading the CSS.

I can change the link colors by adding html  change to the body of the page, but I’d prefer not to:

```
<style>
a {color: yellow;}
</style>
```

This changes all links, not what I wish to do.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you're using some kind of CSS preprocessor that supports nesting, then your CSS is invalid. Once the browser sees the `a` tag inside the `#menu`, it stops working because it expects a CSS property to be there and not another element selector.

To get the correct styling, do this:

```
#menu a {
  color: #FFFF00;
}
```

If you want to style only links that have not been visited, do something like this:

```
#menu a:not:visited {
  color: #FFFF00;
}
```

Comment: Yes, that did change the color of the links.  Thank you very much.  You are also correct that the "a"  stopped the browser from providing the margin that I wanted.  Is it possible to re-format my CSS to provide for the very desirable link color change as well as the margin?  You've been VERY helpful.  Thanks.

Comment: If you want the margin as well, just add another CSS rule for `#menu`. Something like: `#menu { margin-left: 25px; font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; }`.

Comment: Yep, that did it.  Thank you very much.  I'll mark this as resolved.

Comment: Glad I could help.